# Pyglet Subclassing Sprite in 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

In python 3.7.7 with Pyglet 1.5.2
I am trying to inherit from pyglet's Sprite

however if I input the image, x, y which are the first 3 arguments required to init the sprite class.
It gets garbage collected right away

I want to inherit pyglet's Sprite without this occuring

```
class BaseEntity(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

the only way of figuring out this problem is by
not inheriting the class and creating the sprite inside the object

```
class BaseEntity:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # This works because the sprite object is referenced, so it won't be GC'd
        # I don't want to do this though
        self.Sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there a solution to prevent having to do the one below?

Comment: This might very well be a bug. I remember having similar issues, mainly with sprite textures tho. Could you perhaps post this to their issue board: https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/issues?

Answer (score 0):

So this works for me, and this is how I set up a inherited sprite.
By default, I'll create a batch if none was specified, which some times used to help a bit.

```py
class genericSprite(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, *args, **kwargs):
        if not 'batch' in kwargs: kwargs['batch'] = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        if not 'x' in kwargs: kwargs['x'] = 0
        if not 'y' in kwargs: kwargs['y'] = 0

        self.texture = pyglet.image.load(image)

        pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.texture, **kwargs)

    def render(self):
        self.batch.draw()
```

I have no issues with garbage collection on this piece of code.
Now, I ran your code and I can't reproduce the issue, so I'm suspecting it has to do with how you setup your `BaseEntity` call. So if this doesn't work for you *(I would also recommend updating both Python and Pyglet to the latest version as of today)*, put a comment and edit your question to show how you initialize your class.